# Yii 1.1.16 PHP routing rule with two parameters

Tags: php, url, yii, url-routing

I have written URL rule which looks like this:

`'posts/<username:(\w+)>/<title:(\w+)>' => 'posts/view'`

Underneath I also have default rules:

```
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

It generates URL as I would expect something like this `posts/kami/Post+title`, however when you click on the link it gives error: `Error 404. The system is unable to find the requested action "kami".`

So I tried moving the rule under the default rules, because I was guessing that they break my rule, however, if I move my rule under the default rules, it creates different URL, which looks like this: `books/view?username=kami&title=Post+Title`, the link does work as expected, but I don't like the way it looks.

Anyone has any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the rule to

```
'posts/<username:\w+>/<title:.*?>' => 'posts/view'
```

The problem is that \w+ only includes [a-zA-Z0-9_].

So the `+` (**or whitespace**) in `Post+title` is breaking the rule

Comment: Technically `\w` includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. `\w+` with the plus simply means "matched 1 to infinity times".